# Convert a Date in to integer SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a new column "DateID" in the same table "OEMAIN" with a new date format. I have a column called EntryDate which is formatted "2011-01-05 00:00:00" (datetime2(0), null) I would like to pull from that column and make another column called DateID "YYYYMMDD" (int, not null) What would be the coding I would use to do that? I know this is probably a basic question but I can't seem to wrap my brain around it. Thanks

Comment: I am assuming this is for SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the field `DateId`, you can calculate it as:

```
select (year(o.EntryDate) * 10000 + month(o.EntryDate) * 100 + day(o.EntryDate)) as DateId
from oemain o;
```

If you want to include this in the table as a "column", I would suggest a computed column:

```
alter table oemain
    add DateId as (year(EntryDate) * 10000 + month(EntryDate) * 100 + day(EntryDate));
```

That way, you don't have to worry about keeping the `DateId` column in sync with the `EntryDate` column.  The computation happens automatically.

Comment: I am getting an error when I try to run the second one. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "o.EntryDate" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "o.EntryDate" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "o.EntryDate" could not be bound.

Comment: @David . . . The table aliases didn't belong in the computed column definition.  Copy and paste error.

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean by copy and paste error. I ran the first one and it gives me exactly what I want but I am not sure how to move that data to the table column.